# Make a 60° angle on line $l$

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

We have got Line $l$ and point $P$ which is not on $l$. By using a compass and a non-graded ruler, draw a line from $P$ that makes a 60° angle with line $l$.
Please help me!

Comment: Take the compass with any amplitude, stand on the line $l$ at some point $A$ and draw a circle. Stand on one of the intersection points $B$ of the circle with the line and draw another circle (with the same aperture of the compass). The point $A$, the point $B$ and one of the points $C$ of intersection of the two circles form an equilateral triangle. Drawing a line $s$ through $A$ and $C$ gives you a line forming $60$ degrees with $l$. Now draw a line parallel to $s$ passing through $P$ solves your problem. Let me know if you don't know how to draw a parallel to a line passing through a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtain $P'$ by reflection of $P$ across $\ell$; then find $M\in\ell$ such that the triangle $PP'M$ is equilateral. Then draw $g$ through $P$ orthogonal to $M\vee P$.